# How do I retexture two objects so they look like one?

Tags: texturing

I'm editing pants model with ivory/white .dds texture which consist of two overlapping objects: upper legs (selected with vertices) and groins. Problem is that because the texture is applied differently on these objects groins stand out - they look kind of like pampers.

[image]

I'd prefer the texture to be applied more smoothly like in the original version:

[image]

I tried googling but 3d modelling and actually any kind of graphical work is rather alien to me, I'm not even sure what's the industry name for this problem (seaming?), but I guess it's not uncommon so should be relatively easy to fix?

I'm using the newest stable Blender version (2.82) and .nif format.

Comment: I'm not an expert on UV unwrapping, but I suggest doing some research on the fundamentals of unwrapping organic models, because it is never a straight forward answer I think. The solution is always very model dependent. If you understand the fundamentals of unwrapping you should have no problem with something like this. I can't really give you a straight answer to this. I also suggest uploading the .blend file so somebody can have a look at your specific model and help you accordingly.

Comment: @Hendriks3D Thanks for hints, but now I have a feeling I might not be modelling it the right way to begin with, isn't it a better practice to join the vertices of two objects at their edges, rather than shoddily inserting one object into another (which causes overlapping)? Maybe when objects are joined gracefully the textures would look more naturally automatically?

Comment: I didn't know you hadn't merged the meshes. Yes, that's absolutely the better option. Overlaps are always going to look bad unless you model clothes over them.